# Keyframe rotate not progressing

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I am creating a pretty simple keyframe, but for some reason, the rotate portion of the frame I cannot figure out.

I want the keyframe to make two transitions. Here is in illustration, which explains what I am trying to do better. As you can see in my snippet, the rectangle doesn't continue rotation, but goes back to its original postion. Then if I try to do `180deg` it still doesn't work, as it eventually goes back.

I am just wanting the square to turn a total of 180 degrees.

[image]

```css
#line {
  border: 1px solid #8a32cb;
 height: 300px;
  width: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);transform: rotate(0deg);
 transition: 1s;-webkit-transition: 1s;
 /*animation: spin 2s ease-in-out forward;*/
 animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 2s;
 animation-delay: .7s;
 animation-direction: forward;
 animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes spin {
    25%  {-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);transform: rotate(90deg);}
    50% {-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);transform: rotate(90deg);}
    /*50% {-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);transform: rotate(180deg);}*/
}
```

```html
<div id="line"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the animation. I've added [`animation-fill-mode: forwards;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode), and a `100%` state. I've also made the top line wider so we can see the animation:

```css
#line {
  border: 1px solid #8a32cb;
  border-top-width:5px;
 height: 300px;
  width: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);transform: rotate(0deg);
 transition: 1s;-webkit-transition: 1s;
 /*animation: spin 2s ease-in-out forward;*/
 animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 2s;
 animation-delay: .7s;
 animation-direction: forward;
 animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes spin {
    25%  {-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);transform: rotate(90deg);}
    50% {-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);transform: rotate(90deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);transform: rotate(180deg);}
}
```

```html
<div id="line"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I didn't know I had to add a 100% state. I appreciate it!